# Can't access basic Hello World application launched on Amazon EC2 windows server using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I tried to look for solutions and most of them talk about adding HTTP, RDP, HTTPS to security group which I have already done. I have a basic hello world nodeJS application running on Amazon Windows Server 2012. I want to access this application using DNS but it's showing `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in my local laptop browser.

Configuration:

I have RDP, HTTPS, HTTP, SSH, Custom TCP Protocol with 9000 port (nodeJS is running on port 9000) for inbound rules and for outbound default "All traffic" rule is present. I have not done any changes in the Windows Server 2012 configuration. WHen I run localhost:9000 in the windows server 2012 then server returns "Hello World" but when I try that on my local machine with `DNS : 9000` then it says `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Can you give more details about what you have tried so far? Have you tried ssh'ing into your EC2 instance and calling your application from within the box? Also, a connection time out is usually a sign of either a firewall/security group misconfiguration (like you pointed out) or you might be behind an HTTP proxy. Have you tried setting an HTTP proxy when you're calling your application?

Comment: @Viccari please check the updated info in the question. I will really appreciate it if anyone could help you. I am unaware of what you say. So please tell me how to use  your solution

Comment: You might also need to open the port(s) on the Windows Firewall.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that?

Comment: Thanks @Viccari your suggestion worked. I had to add the port in the firewall as New Rule and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's support. Special thanks to Viccari. His suggestion (in the comments below the question) worked. I needed to add the port to the firewall. So basically after adding all the protocols to the security group, I had to add the new port on which the NodeJS is working, to the firewall in the server. Finally its working.